# What are the composition series for these series of groups?

Tags: gr.group-theory, braid-groups

A rack is an algebra $(X,*,*^{-1})$ that satisfies the identities

1. $x*(y*z)=(x*y)*(x*z)$ and
2. $x*(x*^{-1}y)=x*^{-1}(x*y)=y$.

If $X$ is a rack then define a homomorphism $\phi_{n,X}:B_{n}\rightarrow \mathrm{Sym}(X^{n})$ by letting
$\phi_{n,X}(\sigma_{i})(x_{1},\dots,x_{n})=(x_{1},\dots,x_{i-1},x_{i}*x_{i+1},x_{i},x_{i+2},\dots,x_{n})$ for all $i$.

Let $T_{k}$ be the rack of all transpositions in the symmetry group $S_{k}$ with conjugation as the rack operation. In other words, $x*y=xyx^{-1}$ for $x,y\in T_{k}$. What are the simple groups in the composition series for $\phi_{n,T_{3}}[B_{n}]$?

Comment: What do you know at this point? the cardinal of $\phi_{n,T_3}[B_n]$?

Comment: The only thing that I know is that there are 6 orbits, namely $\{(x,\dots,x)\}$ for $x\in T_{3}$ and the orbits of the form $\{(x_{1},\dots,x_{n}):x_{1}\dots x_{n}=a\}$. I have been able to show that there is some quotient group of a subgroup of $\phi_{n,T_{5}}[B_{n}]$ isomorphic to $S_{2^{\lfloor n/2-10\rfloor}}$, but I do not have any similar analysis for $\phi_{n,T_{3}}[B_{n}]$. At this point, I do not have a cardinality of $\phi_{n,T_{3}}[B_{n}]$.

Comment: These are seven subsets, the six latter ones forming a partition.

Comment: I meant to write $\{(x_{1},...,x_{n}):x_{1}...x_{n}=a,\exists i,j: x_{i}\neq x_{j}\}$. Only three of these six latter orbits are non-empty since $x_{1}...x_{n}$ is an even permutation precisely when $n$ is even.